# postgres error: invalid regular expression: brackets [] not balanced

Tags: postgresql, regular-expression

On the postgres command line, I tried this:

```
select 
regexp_matches('file?device_id[]=555', 'device_id\[\]=(\d+)', 'g') as dev_id;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: brackets [] not balanced
```

When I run this same query in HeidiSQL it returns with no errors. I don't understand why the CLI thinks the brackets are unbalanced when I'm escaping them. Just for testing, I tried anywhere from 0 to 3 backslashes to escape the brackets, and none of those worked.

Comment: Gives 
`dev_id
{555}` [for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=89023356b6281d193684b329c2057ca1)!

Comment: How exactly do you run this "on the postgres command line"? Because this [works for me](https://i.imgur.com/HsBDGZk.png) in `psql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I started psql on our local server and ran it there. We have postgres version 9.5.6. I'm not sure if that's a factor.

Comment: Works just fine on [9.5.25](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=bace0ffdc936c3a3ead4ad41102fe89d) - not sure if there was a major functionality shift between 9.5.6 and .25 - **but**, any and all of the 9 versions are now End of Life and no longer supported - time for an upgrade!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer in this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618350/escaping-bracket-in-postgresql-query

After running

```
set standard_conforming_strings=1;
```

It now returns the expected 555.

Comment: Must be an issue with your server setup - as far as I can see, the normal setup returns the correct answer!